# Is it possible to set kerberos authentication server on linux machine only without any extra server or Active Directory

Tags: kerberos

**Kerberos on linux**

Is it possible to set kerberos authentication server on linux machine only without any extra server or Active Directory.
All I have is one linux machine and I have to set up kerberos on it, also how can I verify if it is working properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you done so far? Kerberos works perfectly fine in a one host setup. You just need auth sources

Comment: I have followed the kerberos installation guide http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/www/krb5-1.2/krb5-1.2.6/doc/install.html but still I was facing several issues during configure and installation step.

Comment: Your question is more apropriate in the other stackexchange site: http://serverfault.com/